# Existence of ergodic measure for measurable maps

Tags: ergodic-theory

The existence of ergodic measures is usually proved under the assumptions that the space $\Omega$ is compact metric and the transformation $T: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ is continuous, by using results on the existence of extreme points. Is it possible to establish the existence of ergodic measures  if $T: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ is only a measurable transformation? ($\Omega$ can still be assumed compact metric.) If not, is there any extra condition that would be sufficient for this (of course, weaker than continuity of $T$)?

Comment: Measurability alone is not enough to guarantee existence of invariant (or ergodic) measures.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94981/krylov-bogoliubov-for-measurable-transformations and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66669/proof-of-krylov-bogoliubov-theorem/66676#comment220217_66676

Comment: $x\mapsto x+1$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is the standard counterexample, if you want $\Omega$ to be compact you can take $[0,1]$ with $T\colon x\mapsto x/2$ for $x>0$ and $T(0)=1$.

Comment: Great, thanks. But would then a sufficient condition be the existence of an invariant measure?

Comment: Yes, if $T$ is a measurable transformation and $\mu$ is a $T$-invariant measure, then there must exist an ergodic measure.  This is using the ergodic decomposition, see for example this question: http://mathoverflow.net/q/124066/5701

Answer (score 5):

As indicated in the comments, measurability alone is not enough, and there are easy counterexamples.

As for a condition between continuity and measurability that still does the trick, I'm not sure if there's a natural one.  Using Lusin's theorem one can prove that Condition **(C)** below is equivalent to existence of an invariant measure, but it's not a particularly pleasant condition, as you'll see.  Here we assume that $\Omega$ is a complete separable metric space (not necessarily compact), and $f\colon \Omega\to \Omega$ is measurable (nothing more yet...)

**(C)** There exist a sequence of points $x_k\in \Omega$ and times $n_k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a compact set $K_\epsilon\subset \Omega$ satisfying:  (1) $f|_K$ is continuous, and (2) $\#\{1\leq j\leq n_k \mid f^j(x_k) \in K_\epsilon\} \geq (1-\epsilon)k$ for all sufficiently large $k$.

If you have an invariant measure, you can use the ergodic decomposition to get an ergodic measure, and then the Birkhoff ergodic theorem together with Lusin's theorem to show that **(C)** holds.  On the other hand, if **(C)** holds then by considering the empirical measures $\mu_k = \frac 1{n_k} \sum_{j=0}^{n_k} \delta_{f^jx_k}$ one can observe the following:

1. $\mu_k(K_\epsilon)>1-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$ and all large $k$, and hence the sequence $\mu_k$ is tight, so by Prohorov's theorem it has a convergent subsequence $\mu_{k_i}\to \mu$.
2. If $D$ is a metric on the space of probability measures on $\Omega$ that induces the weak* topology, then $D(\mu, f_*\mu) \leq D(\mu,\mu_k) + D(\mu_k,f_*\mu_k) + D(f_*\mu_k,f_*\mu)$.  The first term goes to zero along $k_i$ by the assumption on the subsequence.  The second term goes to zero along $k$ because the empirical measures are averages over long orbit segments.  The third term goes to zero because $f$ is continuous on $K_\epsilon$ and both $\mu$ and $\mu_k$ put nearly all their weight on $K_\epsilon$.  Thus $D(\mu,f_*\mu)=0$ and so $\mu$ is $f$-invariant.

So **(C)** is equivalent to the existence of an invariant measure.  It's not a terribly nice-looking condition, though.  At the very least you can probably use this to cover some reasonable classes of examples.