# Reference request: stationary measures as convex combinations of ergodic measures

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ergodic-theory

Does anyone know a good reference for the fact that a stationary probability measure is a convex combination of the stationary and ergodic probability measures?

I have found some references for the fact that the ergodic measures are the extreme points of the set of stationary measures, but I don't see how it follows directly from this that all the stationary measures are convex combinations of the extreme points (although maybe I'm missing something obvious).

I also have figured out a quick constructive way to show this fact. If $\mu$ is a stationary probability measure and $\mathcal{I}$ is the shift-invariant $\sigma$-field then we can write
$$
\mu(\cdot) = \int_\Omega \mu( \cdot \, | \mathcal{I} )(\omega) \, \mu(d\omega),
$$
and it's easy to see that for almost every $\omega$ the conditional probability $\mu(\cdot \, | \mathcal{I})(\omega)$ is an ergodic probability measure. I think this is a nice short argument, but I haven't been able to find this or any other reference in the books I've looked at so far.

Comment: In the context of ergodic versus non-ergodic invariant measures of a topological dynamical system this follows from a suitable version of Choquet's theorem, which is a general result describing how a points in a compact convex set can be written as an integral with respect to a measure which gives full measure to the set of extreme points. It is possible that something similar to this works in the abstract measurable setting but I am not sure of the details. This question may be somewhat relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124066/non-existence-of-ergodic-measures

Comment: Choquet's theorem works in a very general settings (std. probability space?), maybe under the name Choquet-Bishop-deLeeuw, or the "disintegration theorem". Check the little book by Phelps called "Lectures on Choquet's theorem"

Comment: And another remark about terminology - a stationary measure (in a Bernoulli system) is nothing more than an invariant measure.

Comment: I wrote a survey on mixing and ergodicity that appears in the (enormous) Springer Encyclopedia of Complexity. I think it's on my web page too. This has an argument along the lines that you're mentioning. I don't think it's as easy as you're saying though. You could also look at Dan Rudolph's book. Again, ergodic decomposition isn't so easy there...

Comment: For what it's worth, the proof of ergodic decomposition in  Rudolph's book works in the generality of Lebesgue spaces

Comment: Asaf: the reason for my hesitation is that I am not sure what locally convex topological vector space would be the ambient space in which the simplex of measures is embedded.

Comment: Asaf: It looks like the Choquet-Bishop-deLeeuw Theorem might be what I'm looking for. I'll have to check the conditions though. Typically the natural topology to work with in the space of probability measures is that of weak-* convergence. So maybe the proper locally convex topological vector space is the space of measures equipped with the weak-* topology (but of course this should maybe be checked).

Comment: Anthony: What about the argument that I give might be more complicated than I think? I think the only sticky point in the argument is the existence of the "regular conditional probabilities" $\mu(\cdot\, | \mathcal{I})(\omega)$. However, this is always okay if the measure $\alpha$ is the distribution of a random variable on a Borel space. In the case that I'm interested in, $\alpha$ is the distribution of a random variable on the space $[0,1]^{\mathbb{Z}}$ so this should be okay.

Comment: @Jon: I guess if you can appeal to a machine to get the regular conditional probabilities, you're left with proving ergodicity of the measure for a.e. omega. I think this is non-obvious.

Comment: What's the problem? Why don't you refer to the standard results on ergodic decomposition in Lebesgue spaces? Are the spaces you are interested in non-separable?

Comment: If you're working on the metrisable topological space $[0,1]^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and looking at shift-invariant measures then all you need to do is use the Choquet-Bishop-de Leeuw Theorem on a compact convex subset of $C([0,1]^{\mathbb{Z}})^*$ with the weak-* topology, and you're done. The result is harder than this only if you're working on a completely abstract probability space, especially one which is not Lebesgue.

Comment: Thanks for all the useful comments. I finally found a good reference in the probability theory literature: Theorem 6.6 in "Probability Theory" by Varadhan (Courant Lecture Notes in Mathematics, volume 7).